# Typeahead no free input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap-typehead function to implement an autocomplete box.

```
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [ "test1", "test2","test3",....];


    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
});
```

Whereas this works, free text can also be as input.  I've noticed many people wanting this functionality and no good explanation for a solution.  What is the best way of modifying this so that entries are only matched to those of availableTags? e.g. if "hello" was entered, it is cleared.

The reason why I want this functionality as opposed to an normal dropdown is that there are thousands of availableTags.  Scrolling down a long list seems illogical.  Thanks

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? I'm not sure to understand it `free text can also be as input`???

Comment: How do you want the value cleared? When the user loses focus on the element?

Comment: @JacquesMarais yes. so if a user clicks away from the element when a tag that isnt in availabletags, for example, it is cleared.

Comment: @A.Wolff if for example, hello was typed in. it normally is accepted even though its not a part of availableTags.  this is what i mean by free text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var availableTags = [ "test1", "test2","test3",....]; // all data required for typeahead

    $(".typeahead").typeahead({
                        source: availableTags
                    })
                    .blur(function(){
                        if(availableTags.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) 
                            $(this).val("");
                    });
});
```

When the user clicks away from the input (loses focus), this checks if the value is inside the array `availableTags`, and if it's not, it sets the input's value back to empty.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however for some reason, the suggested tags of availableTags are now not appearing

Comment: @user47467 there was just an extra `;`. Use your console to debug

Comment: @user47467 Sorry, it was because of a typo.. Try it now

Comment: As a side note, you could use `$(this).data('typeahead').source.indexOf(this.value) === -1` to get relevant source which could be modified in some ways

Comment: @user47467 You should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code